# How to add attribute to asp.net button in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have .NET button having enabled false property.

i have added attribute in following way

```
 OnClientClick="return checkrecord();"
```

I am making it enable in one of my javascript function .

After making it enable it is not calling "checkrecord()" function..

I need to add attribute to my button in javasript so that it can call my another javacsript function on clientclick...

If I am removing enabled false property then it is making call to that function

button is like following which has enabled=flase property

```
<asp:Button ID="btncnclbkng" CssClass="divskyblue"    runat="server"  Text="CANCEL BOOKING" Enabled="false"
                                         Width="410px"  OnClientClick="return checkrecord();"  />
```

I am making it enable in javascript function as follows

```
document.getElementById("btncnclbkng").disabled = false;
```

But it doesnt give call to checkrecord function
If i remove enabled false property then it works

Comment: add ur asp.net and jquery code

Comment: It was spelling mistake

Comment: paste ur design code and script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like below inside your function

```
  $( "#buttonId" ).bind( "click", function() {
        alert( "User clicked on 'button.'" );
  });
```

Note that the `OnClientClick` is a server side event but `click` is a client side event.

Answer (score 0):

try `onclick="return checkrecord()"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery on it like you are using on any normal button

```
#("yourbtnid").click(function(){
alert("buttonclicked");
//do your stuffhere
});
```

or like you are already doing `OnClientClick="checkrecord(this);"`

Define a checkrecord in jquery file included or in same page

```
checkrecord function(e)
{
  alert("button clicked");
}
```